# Google Data Catalog systems list not refreshing

Tags: google-data-catalog

I am using the connector suggested in some GCP documentation to sync metadata from Tableau to Google Data Catalog (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datacatalog-connectors-bi). The sync process goes as expected and I am able to search and explore the data. However the list of available systems does not get updated after several days. Not sure if there is something else you need to do in order to make this happen.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "available systems"  you are referring to? The drop box showed in the image refers to the system field in a search, which can only be: BigQuery, Pub/Sub and/or Data Catalog. See the system qualifier in the [search syntax documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/how-to/search-reference#qualified_predicates)

Comment: @Tlaquetzal my expectation is that if I include entries with a user-defined System, it should should show in the dropdown (considering a time period for any cache to be reloaded). I understand you can query using parameters, but my expectation is the UI should also reflect that.

Comment: Got it. It looks like the UI dropdown is hardcoded to Catalog's defined systems. I found that this is already reported to the Data Catalog team [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/175043877) (I'd assume that you report it)  so I'd suggest to follow up there